# Screenshot particular area of screen only screenshots the top-left?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need to screenshot outside of the application:

**X: centerOfScreen-100 to centerOfScreen+100**
**Y: centerOfScreen-100 to centerOfScreen+100**

```
function GetSCREENSHOT: TBitmap;
var
  Locked: Boolean;
  Canvas: TCanvas;
  R: TRect;
begin
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  Result.Width := 200;
  Result.Height := 200;
  Canvas := TCanvas.Create;
  Canvas.Handle := GetDC(0);
  Locked := Canvas.TryLock;
  try
    // just a poor example
    R := Rect(1280 div 2 - 100, 720 div 2 - 100, 1280 div 2 + 100, 720 div 2 + 100);
    Result.Canvas.CopyRect(R, Canvas, R);
  finally
    if Locked then
      Canvas.Unlock;
    ReleaseDC(0, Canvas.Handle);
    Canvas.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I know it's poor written right now, just for testing. I c&p most of the code and I can't figure out why it only copys the top-left area of my screen.

GetDC(0) returns the DC of the entire screen... right? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "only copys" kinda contradicts with your question. Either it copies the top left area or it copies the center of your screen or does it copy the top left area of the center of the screen? *G*

Comment: It ONLY copies the top left area. That means I have to call the function like: `R := Rect(0, 0, 1280 div 2 + 100, 720 div 2 + 100);` and then it works. Its behavior is weird, is there a possibility that you have to start at the top left to capture before you can capture anything else? But that's exactly what I wanted to avoid - capturing not needed areas of the screen...

Comment: Code can be either poorly written or copy-pasted from elsewhere. Which case?

Comment: Well I took the screenshot function from here (by Daniel Wischnewski): http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/de/showcode.php?id=259 and modified it intuitively so it would only copy a specific area instead of copying chunks. But I can't see the point of your question

Comment: In `CopyRect`, you use the same rect twice. That looks wrong to me. The destination rectangle should probably be `Rect(0, 0, Result.Width, Result.Height)`.

Comment: Thanks Rudy I will try. Btw: Why do people downvote this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have no idea why it was downvoted.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have to apologize - that's what I get for c&ping. Of course it was the mistake because the initial function copies the entire screen and uses the last Rect as an offset for the next one. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @FreeConsulting: I thought the right and bottom pixels are excluded?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, you are right, bottom-right pt is outside clipping rect. Scratch that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code captures whatever area of the desktop is specified, puts it into a TBitmap, and displays that bitmap in a TImage on the form.

(I just grabbed a 400 x 400 pixel area starting at position 100, 100 for demonstration, but it works with other areas as well. Adjust as you need.)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DeskDC: HDC;
  SrcRect, DestRect: TRect;
  DeskCanvas: TCanvas;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  DeskDC := GetDC(GetDesktopWindow);
  try
    DeskCanvas := TCanvas.Create;
    DeskCanvas.Handle := DeskDC;

    SrcRect := Rect(100,
                    100,
                    500,
                    500);
    DestRect := Rect(0,
                     0,
                     SrcRect.Right - SrcRect.Left,
                     SrcRect.Bottom - SrcRect.Top);

    Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Bmp.SetSize(DestRect.Width, DestRect.Height);
      Bmp.Canvas.CopyRect(DestRect, DeskCanvas, SrcRect);
      Image1.Picture.Assign(Bmp);
    finally
      Bmp.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow, DeskDC);
  end;
end;
```

To demonstrate that it works well on any screen area, this code will also capture the lower right corner of my secondary monitor with this change:

```
SrcRect := Rect(Screen.DesktopWidth - 500,
                Screen.DesktopHeight - 500,
                Screen.DesktopWidth - 100,
                Screen.DesktopHeight - 100);
```

Comment: Yes thanks I marked it as the accepted answer. Rudy Velthuis pointed out that the mistake in "my" function was `Result.Canvas.CopyRect(R, Canvas, R);`. I c&p'd the code and it was initially used to capture the whole desktop by capturing little parts of the screen and put them together instead of taking one big screenshot. So it used "R" in CopyRect as the offset for the next part.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to copy entire desktop:

```
  DeskTop := TCanvas.Create;
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Bmp.Width := Screen.DesktopWidth;
  Bmp.Height := Screen.DesktopHeight;
  try
    with DeskTop do
      Handle := GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow);
    with Bmp.Canvas do
      CopyRect(Rect(0, 0,Bmp.Width , Bmp.Height),DeskTop, Screen.DesktopRect);
    .....
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
    DeskTop.Free;
  end
```

Comment: Yes, coping the entire Desktop is not a problem for me. I need to capture a specific rectangle of the desktop without capturing the space around

Comment: So you need just replace CopyRect params to:  CopyRect(Rect(0, 0,200 , 200),DeskTop, Rect(Screen.DesktopWidth div 2 -100, Screen.DesktopHeight div 2 -100, Screen.DeskTopWidth div 2 + 100, Screen.DesktopHeight div 2 + 100);

Comment: Or to be more accurately:  Rect(Screen.DesktopLeft + Screen.DesktopWidth div 2 -100, Screen.DesktopRight + Screen.DesktopHeight div 2 -100, .... etc

Comment: Aren't you meant to call `ReleaseDC` on the desktop DC? And do you really use `with` so enthusiastically?

Comment: Why in the world would you use `with` like that? It's actually more keystrokes than not using it, and it's simply poor coding practice.